# How to rank scores but ignore certain values. Using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

Ok so I have a problem, I'm using an elo system to create a ranking system. I also have a variable for the amount of matches they have played, however I would like to remove people with less than 5 games from the ranking.

So I have name, current elo, amount of games played. I would like to rank then descendingly (high elo is better) but ignore all people with No. Of games less than 5.

I'm using nodejs for the rest of the program all my data is stored in a mysql database.My ranking system also needs to have ties, for people with the same elo.

Now i am home i can add my code in.
My database looks like this:

[image: Database]

Its a little more complicated but this is what it will look like.

My code

```js
exports.getUserRank = function(userid, ladder, callback){
    getSingleRow("SELECT `gamesplayed`, `userid` FROM `users` WHERE `userid` = ?", userid, function(played) {
        console.log(played.gamesplayed);
        if(played.gamesplayed > 10){
            makeQuery("SELECT `userid`, `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating`, rank FROM (SELECT `userid`, `gamesplayed`, `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating`," +
                "@curRank := IF(@prevRank = `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating`, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank,  @incRank := @incRank + 1, " +
                " @prevRank := `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating` FROM `users` p, ( SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @incRank := 1)  " +
                " r  ORDER BY `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating` DESC) s WHERE `userid` = ?", userid, function(data) {
                if (data && data[0] && data[0].rank) {
                    callback(data[0].rank);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            if(played.gamesplayed < 10){
                callback("lessthan10");
            }
            else{
            callback(null)
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Now im not sure but the php would look like:

```
SELECT `userid`, `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating`, rank 
FROM (SELECT `userid`, `gamesplayed`, `ladder_ + ladder + "_rating`,
@curRank := IF(@prevRank = `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating`, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank,
@incRank := @incRank + 1, 
@prevRank := `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating` FROM `users` p,
(SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @incRank := 1)r  
ORDER BY `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating` DESC) s WHERE `userid` = ?
```

Now that my code is here i hope somebody can help me.

Comment: What is your SQL query so far? What is your table layout?

Comment: do you know how to rank at all? because for your question looks like you only have problem with the 5 games part, so you should show us the rest of the code. Also how you want handle ties? Show us some example of your data with the expected result you want.

Comment: Have the ranks set up pretty well, I know I should have waited to get home. I will update with code and yes it's mainly just the 5 match minimum problem. @Juan Carlos Oropdza

Answer (score 1):

If you already know how to calculate rank

```
 SELECT *, rank
 FROM allTable
```

is very easy, just filter your original table

```
SELECT *, rank
FROM ( SELECT *
       FROM allTable
       WHERE NoOfgames >=5
     ) as filterTable
```

Comment: I have updated my code i hope this help. would this change anything?

Comment: Yes, looks like your query just add `WHERE users.gamesplayed > = 5` and should work

Comment: Do you mean in "_rating` FROM `users` WHERE users.gamesplayed > = 5 p," here or at the end, "_rating` WHERE users.gamesplayed > = 5 DESC "?
on in another compleately differnt place?

Comment: Looks like on the first one. But just a suggestion next time just ask the question using plain SQL not  use the PHP version, try to keep it simple.

Comment: That sort of worked with some tweeking thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to fix my problem, thanks partly to @Juan Carlos Oropeza Thank you.

```
exports.getUserRank = function(userid, ladder, callback){
    getSingleRow("SELECT `gamesplayed`, `userid` FROM `users` WHERE `userid` = ?", userid, function(played) {
        console.log(played.gamesplayed);
        if(played.gamesplayed > 10){
            makeQuery("SELECT `userid`, `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating`, rank FROM (SELECT `userid`, `gamesplayed`, `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating`," +
                "@curRank := IF(@prevRank = `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating`, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank,  @incRank := @incRank + 1, " +
                " @prevRank := `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating` FROM (SELECT `userid`, `gamesplayed`, `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating` FROM `users` WHERE `gamesplayed` >=10) p," +
                " ( SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @incRank := 1)  " +
                " r  ORDER BY `ladder_" + ladder + "_rating` DESC) s WHERE `userid` = ?", userid, function(data) {
                if (data && data[0] && data[0].rank) {
                    callback(data[0].rank);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            if(played.gamesplayed < 10){
                callback("lessthan10");
            }
            else{
                callback(null)
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Hope this helped anybody that needed it.